# 404 Not Found: @angular/cli@latest

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Since I clean my cache i'm unable to install angular cli i'm getting :

```
npm install @angular/cli@latest                             
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @angular/cli@latest
```

node version : 8.4
npm version : 5.3.0

any idea on this one ?

Comment: check your node and npm verison

Comment: @Robert I added the versions

Comment: Restart computer maybe will help :-) checked on my machine everything works.

Comment: already tried :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found out the issue :

in my .npmrc I got some weird authentication defined

```
cat ~/.npmrc 
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
email=xxx@xx.com
always-auth=true
_auth="blabla"
```

Just needed to remove

```
email=xxx@xx.com
always-auth=true
_auth="blabla"
```